# Angular bundle js files to html header

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I use Angular 5 AOT to build my website. It work well but It has low score on google spacespeed.
After I have spend lots of time to troubleshoot, I wonder why bundled js files are always at the bottom of index.html.
How do I bring those bundled js files to html header. It is the way to force bundled js files be downloaded first.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is better to leave the bundled js files at the bottom because [they block parallel downloads](https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom).

Comment: If the page has plenty of images, browser downloads images first then it blocks bundled js files util downloading images finish.